# Rails - Confirmation Fields Are Tied to HTML Form Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rails-activerecord, password-confirmation

Rails only checks for field confirmations if there is a corresponding `_confirmation` field in the request.

To explain it further, here is a sample Rails view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>

<% end %>
```

This form works as expected.

However, if you remove:

```
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
```

Passwords are no longer confirmed.

The problem I am having is all my `JSON` requests are going through successfully without a corresponding `_confirmation` field.

This request is successful:

```
{
    "email": "me@example.com",
    "password" : "somepassword"
}
```

This is not:

```
{
    "email": "me@example.com",
    "password" : "somepassword",
    "password_confirmation": "_somepassword 
}
```

Also, for the second JSON, if `password` and `password_confirmation` match then the request is successful(which is understood).

I think the first request should not be successful since there is no password confirmation.

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour since confirmation fields should be tied to ActiveRecord and not HTML from helpers.

How will one replicate field confirmations in Rails based JSON APIs then?

Comment: This has nothing to with the form helper - its just about the behavior of `validates_confirmation_of` which allows nil. Which is kind of sensible with regards to API's. Password confirmations are just a (somewhat annoying) way of helping the user ensure the he typed the password as intended. It has no actual security value.

Answer (score 1):

I think that validation of the confirmation is kind of useless in the context of an JSON API. You would basically only validate that the developer read your API description.

Therefore I would argue that it makes sense that it does not validate if the confirmation key is missing. Since a form would always return both fields it would always validate user input.

If you really want to enforce the confirmation (even on the JSON API) just follow the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_confirmation_of):

> NOTE: This check is performed only if `password_confirmation` is not `nil`. To require confirmation, make sure to add a presence check for the confirmation attribute:
>
> `validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, if: :password_changed?`